# Confusing behavior of C code with shadowed struct declaration

Tags: c, callstack, shadowing

Consider the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
} TestType;

int main(){
    int an_int;
    TestType test;
    // printf("%d\n",test.a);
    {
        TestType test;
        test.a = 777;
        printf("offset: %lld\n", &test.a - &an_int); // maybe 2?
    }
    printf("%d\n", test.a);                        // should be garbage
    printf("offset: %lld\n", &test.a - &an_int);     // maybe 1?    
}
```

I declare a `TestType test`, then start a scope and declare another `TestType test` shadowing the first. The expected output of the print statement at the end is whatever was on the stack. Compiling with `gcc -o stack-allocate-weird stack-allocate-weird.c` and running, I get output:

```
offset: 1
777
offset: 1
```

So the two locations are the same. Furthermore, `valgrind ./stack-allocate-weird` reports no errors. Uncommenting the first print statement gives me the expected output:

```
-771776240
offset: 2
-771776240
offset: 1
```

If instead of `struct TestType` I just declare an `int`, the code behaves as expected (the last print statement prints garbage).

I put the code onto a server and compiled it and got:

```
offset: -2
0
offset: -1
```

Which looks fine too (I guess the stack goes in the opposite direction?). On the other hand, moving the binary compiled on my computer over to the server gave the original bad output:

```
offset: 1
777
offset: 1
```

Is this a known bug with gcc?

`gcc -v` on my computer says (a bunch of other stuff and):

```
gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04)
```

On the server it says:

```
gcc version 8.3.1 20190223 (Red Hat 8.3.1-2) (GCC)
```

So maybe this got fixed somewhere in between?

Comment: Actually the behaviour of your subtraction is undefined

Comment: `777` is as good a garbage value as any other. You're reading an uninitialized variable - undefined behavior.

Comment: The proper test would be to have the same address from `printf("address: %p\n", (void *)&test.a);` which I can confirm :P

Comment: There is a good question here. but it is not the one that you're asking...

Comment: No, I gave up. It needs a complete rewrite. Especially the part of copying the binary from the server and running it locally, that's impossible! (You didn't do it). The question you should be asking is "is a C compiler allowed to place these structures at the same address"

Comment: @AnttiHaapala He didn't say that... he said it went the other way (he took the binary from his local machine and ran it on the server and got the same bad output), and the result makes sense. :-)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That does sound like the question I should be asking.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister ok it is midnight here :D

Comment: @Hood because from the language lawyering perspective, when I read the standard like the Devil the Bible, it wouldn't be allowed to have these residing at the same address because they're both supposed to be alive at the same time.

Comment: I think it all makes sense now. It's undefined behavior to read an uninitialized value, so C can just let the inside declaration point to the same memory location as the outside one -- I haven't written any of the fields yet so it doesn't matter what's inside of it.

Comment: The nasty thing about this is that it tricks valgrind into thinking the field has been initialized.

Comment: @antti: if you refer to the outer `test` before the inner loop, then it will be separately allocated. But since it is not accessed, the compiler is free to not allocate it until afterwards, using the "as if" exemption. It's address is Heisenberged: it's not definite until it's observed. That's not a bug because at no time do two existing objects have the same observable address.

Comment: I also compiled with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` and gcc didn't warn me about the undefined behavior =(

Comment: @hood: yes, the Valgrind issue is indeed irritating but valgrind cannot be responsible for detecting UB since it works at the binary code level; it never sees the original source code.

Comment: By the way, the fact that the two objects have the same name is probably irrelevant.

Comment: @rici I understand, life is hard sometimes. It's such a simple mistake to copy instead of cut when moving a declaration outside of a scope, so I just wanted to whine about it while I have the audience.

Comment: @rici I was trying to find the part of the standard which would prohibit them from having the same address, but couldn't find - just that there be storage allocated for an object at a constant address and retain the last stored value... might be worth writing an answer but too late here.

Comment: @antti, footnotes are not normative but they are useful: "The term ‘‘constant address’’ means that two pointers to the object constructed at possibly different times will compare equal." Until you refer to an object, its address is unspecified (or uncertain, as with the Heisenberg analogy).

Comment: @rici Isn't a Heisenberg/bug where the program changes behavior when observed (under a debugger)? I think you're referring to Schrödinger's cat.

Comment: @JL2210: "Heisenbug" is indeed a colloquial expression which is a pun on "Heisenberg" but my analogy is based on a possibly simplistic understanding of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle, which implies that the measurable value was not precise before being measured. Schrodinger's unfortunate feline is a translation of measurement to a coarser category (mortality), but I was actually talking about measurement. In fact, the uncertainty principle AIUI actually says that if you precisely measure some aspect (eg position) then some other aspect (eg. momentum) becomes less precise,...

Comment: ... so my analogy probably wasn't that great, and a better analogy might have been Berkeley's forest (in which the falling trees make no sound until someone shows up to hear them). Berkeley's ontological question is actually extremely pertinent: a declared object might not have a physical presence unless (and until) something observes it (unless it is volatile).

Comment: @rici Schrödinger's cat was never put into practice, thankfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is a bug with GCC. The compiler is delaying the allocation of the outer `TestType test` until it is needed. And this is at your second `printf()` in line 16. The inner `TestType test` is placed at offset 1, like you watched, until its scope is closed and its memory is free again. Now the outer one is needed and takes the very same space, giving you the value of the inner one and the same offset.